# listview displaying image and data from server db in android

Tags: php, android, listview

i need to create a listview in my project which will have to display the product image and data from the server db but i'm not sure how to do it. if anyone can suggest me some idea or guide a tutorial related to this it will be of great help.

P.S : i'm using wamp server and php with CI

listview must look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv2RU.jpg

thanks

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/23/simplest-lazy-loading-listview-android-data-populated-mysql-database-php/

Comment: Following one will provide you exactly the same kind of UI. Check the following link,
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/